# Openfire : installation completed : cannot access admin

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, openfire

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.

Java is installed correctly, since I can run `java -version`

`java version "1.7.0_11"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_11-b21)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.6-b04, mixed mode)`

Installed OpenFire using these commands :

1. wget http://download.igniterealtime.org/openfire/openfire_3.7.1_all.deb
2. dpkg -i openfire_3.7.1_all.deb

The output was :

```
Selecting previously unselected package openfire.
(Reading database ... 67858 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking openfire (from openfire_3.7.1_all.deb) ...
Setting up openfire (3.7.1) ...
adduser: Warning: The home directory `/var/lib/openfire' does not belong to the user you are currently creating.
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
```

There are 2 problems :
1.) There is no "openfire" folder in "/opt"
2.) When I hit the 9090 port on the external port, it doesn't go through.
3.) `ps -ef | grep openfire` doesn't yield anything. Tried grepping "java" & "jive" as well.

I'm trying to understand if OpenFire is really installed correctly or not

Answer (score 1):

> Warning: The home directory `/var/lib/openfire' does not belong to the user you are currently creating.

That seems like a pretty major clue. I assume the user should be `openfire`? Then change ownership like so:

```
chown -R openfire:openfire /var/lib/openfire
```

Also, [check these setup instructions](http://library.linode.com/communications/xmpp/openfire/ubuntu-10.04-lucid#sph_configure-openfire). Specifically the firewall settings. Tons of ports seem to need attention.

And check the [source of the install script](http://svn.igniterealtime.org/svn/repos/openfire/trunk/build/debian/openfire.postinst) for more clues on directory permissions.

Comment: user "openfire" already has the access to this directory & all the one's inside it.

Comment: No firewall configuration, hence no port openings required. Also, added the ip to the <interface> tag in openfire.xml

Comment: yup, I ran it. Also after the install I restarted the linux server(I don't think it was required, but still tried it.)

Comment: Thanks Jake. I learned that many are straight away using the tar ball. Going to try that now